# Optimised MongoDB design for access control at project/organisation level

Tags: database-design, mongodb, access-control

I'm looking for the optimised approach of designing MongoDB database collections where there are three stakeholders-

- A **User** (who accesses a portal).
- An **Organization** (which can have multiple Projects).
- A **Project** (which will be inside a single Organization).

A user can be added either to an Organization, which will give them access to all the projects within the organization, or they can be added to a project level.

(Considerable examples- Firebase/GCP organization/project access or Gitlab's access control)

**An example to explain-**

- Org1 has two projects P1, P2
- Org2 has one project P3,
- Org3 has three projects P4, P5, P6
- User1 is added as `ADMIN` to ORG1
- User2 is added as `VIEWER` to P3
- User3 is added as `MANAGER` to P4 & P6.

This results in in-

- User1 can manage, delete and change settings for any current/future projects in Org1.
- User2 can view settings only on P3 but won't see any other future projects in Org2.
- User3 can only manage settings of P4 & P6 but can't see P5.

What can the best approach to store & query this data so that validating a user’s access control for every request should be efficient and simpler and can provide results in the shortest number of DB calls?

Comment: What should the behavior be if a user is added to both an organization *and* one or more projects of that same organization? Should the project rights overrule the organization rights, should the rights be merged, something else?

Comment: Though I can take care of that later once the schema is finalised but yes, project rights should overrule organisation rights.